# Listbox doesn't always show items based on other listbox

Tags: javascript, mysql, listbox

Based on a value of one listbox (selecttreatment), another listbox (indicators) options are being populated. The `javascript` code i use:

```
function sendData() { // onchange
    $("#indicators").empty();
    console.log($("#selecttreatment").val());
    $.getJSON("functions/getcharts.php", {funcid:"giveme_chosen_treatment", chosen_treatment: $("#selecttreatment").val()}, updateData);
}

function updateData(data) {
    console.log(data);

    var option = '';
    for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
       //option += '<option value="'+ data[i].zi_indicator_name_id + '">' + data[i].zi_indicator_name_label + '</option>';
       option += '<option value="'+ data[i].indicator_name + '">' + data[i].indicator_name + '</option>';
    }
    $('#indicators').append(option);

}
```

At first I believed it only went wrong when mysql gives back one row, but that isn't the problem. I can't fugure out whats going wrong.

So my problem is that sometimes the 2nd listbox is being populated with values, but most of the times it isn't.

Comment: request is async, it will take time to populate another dropdown.

Comment: But if I type the url with the varibles in my browser it also gives no JSON data, so that even before the listbox is being populated.